# Use Strict : How to test it?

Tags: javascript

I have been reading people recommending using "use strict" option. As mentioned [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/13/its-time-to-start-using-javascript-strict-mode/?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email)

every major browser supports strict mode in their latest version, including Internet Explorer 10 and Opera 12. I wanted to test it with IE10 and i have following code segemnt. IE 10 /FF did not gave any error message. What am i missing ? How do i test that "use strict" is actually working if i make any mistake ?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
"use strict";
function doSomething(value1, value1, value3) {
     alert('hello');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
hello
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see in this example that Chrome actually complains about the duplicate argument name:

http://jsfiddle.net/vANfY/

Comment: ahh !!! dumb me...thanks. :) Got it. But how do i get same error in my browser ? Everytime i cant paste code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

firefox throws 'duplicate formal argument value1',

IE10 throws 'Duplicate formal parameter names not allowed in strict mode'

Comment: I cant see it happening on either FF or IE10. Can you post the screenshot ?